# Adding items to a Google Forms list from a spreadsheet range

Tags: list, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am struggling to get past the last line in this code any help will be appreciated:

The error I am getting is "Array is empty: values (line 16, file "Code")". I have double checked the item ID, the spreadsheet ID and that there is data for it to pick up within the correct range. Any pointers or insights...?

```js
  function GetFleet() {
  var ssDEFECTS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var rngFLEET = ssDEFECTS.getDataRange();
  var values = rngFLEET.getValues();
  var FleetList = [];

//Use column 0 and ignore row 1 (headers)
  for (var i = 1; i <= values.length; i++) {
    var v = values[i] && values[i][0];
    v && values.push(v)
  }

  // Form ID & List ID
  var DefectsForm = FormApp.openById('<FORM KEY ID>');
  DefectsForm.getItemById(794194842).asListItem().setChoiceValues(FleetList);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is pushed to your array FleetList. Also the coding in your loop is faulty.
Assuming you want to push the first column (not including the header), 
try this and see if it works

```js
function GetFleet() {
var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheets()[0].getDataRange()
    .getValues();
var FleetList = [];

//Use column 0 and ignore row 1 (headers)
for (var i = 1, len = values.length; i < len; i++) {
    FleetList.push(values[i][0])
}

// Form ID & List ID
var DefectsForm = FormApp.openById('<FORM KEY ID>');
DefectsForm.getItemById(794194842)
    .asListItem()
    .setChoiceValues(FleetList);

};
```

Comment: Thanks user3889423, that has worked really well and gives me exactly what I was looking for.